# Syntax error on an INSTEAD OF TRIGGER CREATION - PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax, triggers

I'm trying to create an INSTEAD OF TRIGGER following the Postgres documentation, but there's a syntax error that I can't find the exact error location.

```
    CREATE TRIGGER TRUpdateRuntime 
        INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON Papeis
        FOR EACH ROW
        REFERENCING NEW ROW AS N
        UPDATE Movies SET RunTime=N.RunTime WHERE MovieId=Papeis.MovieId
```

I have created the Papeis View before the trigger creation and it keeps bringing this error:

> syntax error at or near "REFERENCING"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot be used with `INSTEAD OF` trigger. See:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html

"This option is only allowed for an AFTER trigger that is not a constraint trigger; ..."

Comment: Thanks! I also found out that you can't run SQL directly on a trigger without creating a procedure or function in postgres.

Answer (score 0):

Adrian's answer is right.

But the immediate cause of the syntax error is that the `REFERENCING` clause must come before the `FOR EACH` clause.